# How should a file: URI corresponding to a Windows path name look like?

Tags: java, file, url, jar

I am trying to load a MySQL jar dynamically in code but I am unsure about the format of the Windows path name.  Is what I am using below correct, for loading a .jar from a thumbdrive?

```
URL u = new URL("jar:file:G:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar!/");
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u });
```

Now, this is not the same as the traditional path that you see in Java tutorials:

```
URL url = new URL("file:/g:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar");
```

For the answer, I am looking for clarification; I guess I am just confused by the "jar:file:" thing and also the "!" at the end.

Comment: [Actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), `file:///g:/...` for files on the local system. Without the slashes, it is a

Answer (score 7):

Using `toURI()` method on the `File` object should do the trick:

```
final URL u = new File("g:/something.jar").toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u });
```

Comment: Ill try System.out.println( myfile.toURI() ) later and let you know what happens.